# Django staticfiles with cache busting

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to migrate my project from using {% compress %} to grunt for the whole front-end workflow. I got my grunt setup correctly and I can generate my main.min.css and main.min.js. With collectstatic I see them copied to the right folder, but when I deploy to staging all I get is a big fat 500 error.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'captcha',
'core',
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
"django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
"django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
"compressor.finders.CompressorFinder",
)
```

and in the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "core/dist/css/main.min.css" %}" />
```

It works locally if I set DEBUG=False in settings.py (without loading the static files obviously). Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone ending up here in the future: check your .gitignore file and be sure to only reference existing files in the template!

In my case I had `dist/` in my .gitignore and I was storing my static files in core/dist/ so they got gitignored and ended up not being on the server.